# SilverStripe 3.1+ change FileNameFilter default replacements

Tags: filter, filenames, silverstripe

Currently uploading a file with an '_' (underscore) in it is automatically replace with '-' (hyphen). I need them to stay as _ .
The same as this issue: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/issues/719

I've discovered this happens via FileNameFilter http://api.silverstripe.org/master/class-FileNameFilter.html#_setReplacements

I've tried to follow the instructions to stop this by adding this to the YAML config:

```
FileNameFilter:
  default_use_transliterator: false
  default_replacements:
```

This has no effect do  I need to state the new defaults?

And also changing this line:

```
'/_/' => '-', // underscores to dashes
```

to this

```
'/_/' => '_', // underscores to dashes
```

But this just removes them and closes the gap..

Could someone advise on the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised you can do this in your _config.php file too! And this has worked. I'll leave this question up incase this is useful for anyone like me.

_config.php

```
FileNameFilter::$default_use_transliterator = false;
FileNameFilter::$default_replacements = array();
```

Comment: Are you sure it worked? Do you have `error_reporting` set in php.ini? `$default_use_transliterator` is a private static, meaning you cannot modify it outside of the class that defines it (`FileNameFilter` in this case)if you do, you should get a PHP Fatal Error.

My guess is that when you made YML change, you forgot to clear the cache manifest (flush=all) which you need to do, every time you make a YML config change to SIlverStripe's private statics.