# Silverstripe: Trouble with uploading files with cyrillic names

Tags: silverstripe

When I'm uploading in CMS files with cyrillic names, cyrillic symbols just disappears.
For example: filename "мой_файл.txt" becomes just "txt" without "мой_файл."
Filename has windows-1251 encoding.

Firebug shows  :

```
POST /admin/projects/Project/EditForm/field/Project/item/6/ItemEditForm/field/Projects/upload HTTP/1.1
Host: silver.rivreg.ru
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://silver.rivreg.ru/admin/projects/Project/EditForm/field/Project/item/6/edit
Content-Length: 377
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---
```

And at the Post tab shows:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SecurityID"
4754dec1aad707dd63e8cc58c8e469d0bc149425
-----------------------------81762142719766
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Projects[Uploads][]"; filename="Ð¼Ð¾Ð¹_ÑÐ°Ð¹Ð».txt"**
Content-Type: text/plain
ïîëïîïîïîïîïîïîîûûûûûûû
-----------------------------81762142719766--
```

Please give me any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `FileNameFilter` as this is the logic that "cleans-up" incoming / uploaded filenames.

Specifically look at its `$default_replacements` private (config) static. Because it's private static, it can be modified in userland (custom) YML config.

The relevant line is even commented for you:

```
// remove non-ASCII chars, only allow alphanumeric plus dash and dot
```

Override this in your own custom YML config with something that suits the range of characters that your system will accept.

Comment: I added to config.yml 
`FileNameFilter:
  default_use_transliterator: false
  default_replacements:`
, cleared the cache manifest (flush=all) and recieved `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/home/smolin/silver/framework/core/manifest/ConfigManifest.php on line 655`. The behavior of FileNameFilter did not change

Comment: The same situation as in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944404/silverstripe-3-1-change-filenamefilter-default-replacements)

Comment: If you really defined `default_replacements` without anything to its right, then that error is almost definitely SPL failing to parse your invalid YML. You need to *substitute* the ASCII-specific entry found in core's `FileNameFilter` with your own regex based on the requirements of your system (i.e. to include cyrillic characters). All you've done is redefine the `default_replacements` array as "empty" and cause a PHP error.

Comment: From this point on, your problem is almost certainly no longer a SilverStripe problem, but a regex problem. With that in mind, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716609/how-to-match-cyrillic-characters-with-a-regular-expression) with regard to matching Cyrillic characters.

Comment: It seems to me I don't understand YML syntax. I used YML file from [FileNameFiter](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-FileNameFilter.html). But it does't work. Please, can you explain for dummy the YML file structure in this specific case?

Comment: When I use brute force i.e. edit file  framework/filesystem/FileNameFilter.php and insert  `private static default_replacements = array();` all cyrillic names files upload normally. But it's wrong way

Comment: Hi Alex, there are 2 ways of creating/updating SS config: 1 using private static variables (arrays, scalars etc) defined _in the class itself_ 2. YML.

For YML open up your project's own YML config file which is: `mysite/_config/config.yml` and copy/paste the contents of the following gist into it: https://gist.github.com/phptek/9bfc7358191c67827be88f1a817c89d9 

All this is, is the contents of `FileNameFilter::$default_replacements` converted to YML. [see here](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/configuration/configuration/) you will still need to make your mods to it.

Comment: Thank you TheRuss for help! I understood.

Comment: Glad I helped, but helped you learn a little too. And seeing as my original answer helped you, please consider accepting it as "the" answer.